# Trying to upsert product2 - Method not allowed?

Tags: rest-api, force.com, c#, .net, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I am using this library in C# to make REST calls to SalesForce: https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET

I've run into a problem when trying Upsert into Product2. Here is the error message I am getting:

```
[{"errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are GET,HEAD,POST"}]
```

The URL it generates:

```
https://na73.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Product2/ProductID__c/# H6 SHORT BARREL NUT
```

So clearly it wants me to not use upsert. What's weird though is I've been able to upsert on `Accounts` and `Contacts` as well as others. Even weirder is the methods it says are allowed to use on Product2 don't allow me to update existing products - I can only create new ones via POST. How do I update a product via the API?

Below is the code/payload I am working with just in case I'm doing something wrong...

```
public async Task<bool> UpsertProduct(SalesForceProduct product, string salesForceField, string salesForceFieldValue)
{
    bool Authenticated = await Authenticate();

    if (!Authenticated)
    {
        throw new Exception("[UpsertProduct] Failed to Authenticate");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("[UpsertProduct] Upserting a potentially new product");

    var upsertProductResponse = await forceClient.UpsertExternalAsync(SalesForceProduct.SObjectTypeName, salesForceField, salesForceFieldValue, product);
    if (!upsertProductResponse.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[UpsertProduct] An error occurred upserting product {product.ProductID__c}: {upsertProductResponse.Errors.ToString()}");
        return false;
    }

    // The upserts for accounts work this way so I am guessing Product2 is - but I haven't made it this far yet...
    product.Id = upsertProductResponse.Id;

    if (product.Id == string.Empty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[UpsertProduct] Updated existing product: {product.ProductID__c}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[UpsertProduct] Created new product: {product.Id}");
    }

    return upsertProductResponse.Success;
}
```

And how I call the Upsert function:

```
var hProducts = sql.GetAllProducts();
var convertedProducts = Utilities.STORISProductToSalesForce(hProducts);

SalesForceProduct product = convertedProducts[0];                

await sfREST.Authenticate();
await sfREST.UpsertProduct(product, "ProductID__c", product.ProductID__c);
```

And the payload (`product`) I am trying to Upsert:

```
{"BrandID__c":"<No Value>","CaseSellPrice__c":0.0000,"Class__c":"","Color__c":"","DealCasePrice__c":0.0000,"DepthDimension__c":0.0,"Description2__c":"","GroupID__c":"<No Value>","KitOnly__c":"False","KitStatus__c":"N","Name":"<Unknown>","PieceSellPrice__c":0.0000,"ProductBenefits__c":"","ProductCode":"# H6 SHORT BARREL NUT","ProductID__c":"# H6 SHORT BARREL NUT","ProductTypeID__c":9999,"SpecialOrder__c":true,"Status__c":"","Style__c":"","SuggRetailPrice__c":0.0000,"VendorID__c":"<No Value>","WebAvailableOnWeb__c":"False","WebBenefits__c":""}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use PATCH, you need to make sure you're encoding the ID. Assuming the URL in your question was generated literally, that's problematic. The URL should look like:

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Product2/ProductID__c/%23%20H6%20SHORT%20BARREL%20NUT
```

Characters other than A-Z, 0-9, #, and _ need to be URL-encoded. As it was, the URL was written in a way that the server couldn't "see" the ID, and assumed you were trying to do an insert, producing the error you received.

---

I feel like this might be a bug in the toolkit; it should automatically be encoding URL parameters for you, but it doesn't. You can encode it yourself by changing a line of code:

```
var upsertProductResponse = await forceClient.UpsertExternalAsync(SalesForceProduct.SObjectTypeName, salesForceField, Uri.EscapeUriString(salesForceFieldValue), product);
```

---

One final note: the External ID field must **not** be specified in your JSON payload. To do so is an error.

---

Demo

---

Incorrect:

[image]

---

Correct:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. I was so focused on the METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED error message I didn't even notice it. I've added the encoding line directly to the library so going forward all calls will be encoded properly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @duckwizzle That was my idea; I might fork the library and make some customizations to it. It looks useful, but it needs some work.

Comment: @sfdcfpx Awesome man. If you do shoot me a link. I have about 2 weeks of Sales Force experience under by belt so if more stuff needs to change I probably won't notice it and would love to see what you improve on. Also, FYI if you make that change, `Uri.EscapeUriString` did not convert `#` to `%23` -  I did it manually after the encoding. I see a lot of product IDs with characters that don't auto encode. This should be fun

Comment: @duckwizzle I'll play with it; it's possible that's the wrong method (I'm not super-familiar with C#, so it'll give me some experience tinkering with this).